# How to set SimpleList for in Admin-on-rest to show Show form in mobile-view when touched on item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

I use admin-on-rest `<SimpleList>` component for mobile view and when my resource doesn't have edit view I get white screen when I clicked on some element.  If resource haven't Edit-view I want to show Show-view for user.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible yet, but it will be in version `2.0.0`. In the mean time, you can create your own `SimpleList` component. Original one is [here](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/src/mui/list/SimpleList.js)